# How to determine the number of rows and columns of DEM in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, dem

I have a AsterDem of resolution 30m for my study area. I want to know the number of columns and rows present in the DEM raster. How do I find it out using ArcGIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Get Raster Properties](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/get-raster-properties.htm) tool in the Data Management toolbox is what you want. Input your AsterDEM raster and run the tool twice-- once to get COLUMNCOUNT and once for ROWCOUNT. The number of cells in each direction will be in your Results window.

[image]